# How to alter entity field in drupal 8?

Tags: hooks

I add field (select list) in Group form (form_id = 'group_drupalcamps_add_form') with UI. Now i want to alter/target that field and pass variable to it. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hook_form_alter().

Answer (score 0):

```php
/**
 * Manage alters for group_drupalcamps_add_form
 *
 * @param $form
 * @param $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'group_drupalcamps_add_form') {
    // alter the field within the $form array
  }
}
```